# CHKDSK in Linux...?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, chkdsk

My computer has taken a dive and it will not boot up. I have reasons to believe that it is the hard drive. I would like to run CHKDSK but I cannot get the computer to boot up into Windows.

My question is this: Is there a way to run CHKDSK from Ubuntu? I can boot into UBuntu using a USB and I can mount and see the hard drive contents (and access them). I was wondering if there is any way I can get chkdsk/r to run and see what happens. (Anyway I can get it to run inside or outside of Ubuntu)

Comment: If you have a Windows 7 install DVD, you can run `chkdsk` from there.

Comment: No Disk. Did not come with computer.

Comment: You should check with the OEM and see if you can get a disk for future use. It may cost a few $$$, but you'd probably be back in business now if they had included one.

Comment: What I learned is to create recovery media when you get your computer. I did not and learning the hard way.

Comment: I don't suppose you have another PC you can transplant the disc into temporarily to do the chkdsk?  In my current experiences with windows 7 chkdsk has not been particularly useful in recovering non booting PCs but good luck.

Comment: @UBhapE2 - OEM recovery media is usually just an image that restores your suytem back to the origianl factory install. It's not a real installation DVD.

Comment: @Col The computer in question is a laptop and is still under warrenty so I will not pull it apart. I am trying to do chkdsk while I wait on the box from Toshiba to see if I can get anything working. If not then it gets mailed in for repair.

Comment: @Joe I realize that. I looked into it and it would cose $35 and their support said it might not fix it because of the error I was having. Its under warranty so I am not going to spend the money on a disk. I will attempt what I can here then send it in if it doesn't work. Thanks for the information. =>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Reboot the computer, and *before* the Windows logo comes up, press F8 a few times.
2. When the menu comes up, select Repair Your Computer (or similar) at the top.
3. When it's finished booting, select the Command Prompt.
4. Run ChkDsk.

Another option (this is tedious):

1. Download and install the [Windows AIK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5753).
2. Create a bootable flash drive with Windows PE on it (it's slightly painful).
3. Reboot using the flash drive, and run ChkDsk.

I would upload an image that I'd already made, but I don't believe I'm allowed to. :\

Comment: when I try that I get a black screen with a white cursor I cannot get to the Command Prompt Screen

Comment: @UBhapE2: When exactly does that happen? (After which step?)

Comment: I Press F8 - I choose Repair Your Computer - It says Windows is Loading then I get a Black Screen with a White Cursor. It will not go past that point (I have let it sit at that screen for over 4 hours)

Comment: @UBhapE2: Ah, I see... Do you think you could try the Windows AIK approach? That's a really good way to run ChkDsk, but it's a little annoying.

Comment: What is the AIK Approach?

Comment: @UBhapE2: I've updated it in my answer. You need to download the Windows Automated Installation Kit, and make a boot CD (or flash drive). It's a little tedious, but if you're willing to try I'd be willing to help you get it working. :) It's pretty much just a command prompt with the vital commands.

Comment: I will attempt this. Lets see what happens.

Comment: Where do I get Windows PE? I Google it and get information on it but not to download it.

Comment: @UBhapE2: It's part of the Windows AIK (which is why I provided the link, and why the download is so large).

Comment: got it, I will post comment here once download is finished. It is quite large. 1.7 GB!

Comment: @UBhapE2: Okay sure! Yeah it's large, it has a lot of tools (not all of which are relevant), but the PE image itself isn't *that* big (around ~130 MB each I think -- there's 3 versions, one for x86, one for x64, one for IA64; you only need the x86 one).

Comment: k, from what I read I must "burn" it to a USB (Laptop does not have Disk Drive) will it do that or what should I use to handle that process?

Comment: @UBhapE2: You obviously don't need to burn the image file you downloaded just so you can install it (you can just use [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/) or something similar to mount a virtual image, and run the installer from there). After you've installed it, go to the Start Menu -> Programs -> Windows AIK (or something similar -- it could also be called "Microsoft Windows AIK" or whatnot) and open the help documentation for Windows PE. Then search for UFD in the index (standing for USB Flash Drive) and try following the instructions. (Back up your UFD's data!!)

Comment: Hmm Avira just stopped the download. Said it contained a Trojan or Virus...starting again

Comment: @UBhapE2: LOL ok.
You might want to use [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) to download it more quickly, btw.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, it was ImDisk that had the virus related to it. But when Avira caught it, it stopped the download.

Comment: @UBhapE2: Ah, I see. ImDisk should be legitimate, it's likely just a false positive because of the kernel-mode driver. Have fun re-downloading it. :-)

Comment: I think it was a flase-positive. I am going to use ImgBurn just in case it is not. => One note: I am uisng an XP computer to do this on yet that computer with an issue is A windows 7. Will there be any issue "installing" this with this computer to do what I must do?

Comment: @UBhapE2: There *shouldn't* be a problem on XP, but I'm not 100% sure, you'll have to try and see. And don't worry, ImDisk is signed and everything, there's nothing wrong with it (but feel free to burn it instead, not like it makes a difference!). :-)

Comment: WOO HOO! DOwnload FInished... FINALLY! About XP I found this: "If installing the WAIK in Windows XP, you may need to install the .NET Framework 2.0 Setup and the MSXML 6.0 Setup before the WAIK will install." From this site: http://www.themudcrab.com/vistapeguide_waik.php MSXML 6.0 is incluided in (XP Service Pack 3)  Now the next step...

Comment: @UBhapE2: Lol. I'm not sure you need the .NET framework -- you probably only need it if you're using some other parts of the tools, but not this part. Try installing it and see if you really need it.

Comment: Well, Image Burn doesn't write to USB so I found this http://wudt.codeplex.com/ and this tool is made for exactly what I am doing. Good to know. I believe ImDisk is a false positive but not taking chances. I am down to one computer right now.

Comment: @UBhapE2: Wait, I'm confused. What file (and why) are you trying to write to a USB? Can't you just extract the downloaded `.iso` file with 7-zip or something? It really shouldn't get this complicated -- you should **NOT** need any external tools to get Windows PE working, once you've installed the Windows AIK.

Comment: I might not need to but I am writing to USB for the simple reason that hard drive space is limited here and with my second computer down I cannot move files that I normally move. So I am keeping a certain amount of space open on the drive. It should not be this complicated and really is isn't just seems that way =>

Comment: @UBhapE2: OK, whatever you say... so long as it works. :)

Comment: got the AIK installed, how do I create the WindowsPE on a bootable flash drive?

Comment: I found and followed these instructions: http://4sysops.com/archives/build-a-bootable-windows-pe-3-0-usb-drive-with-rescue-tools-part-1/

Comment: @UBhapE2: It seems like those are the same things that are in the help file; I think you should just follow what's in the Windows PE help file, just to be safe. (Search for "UFD" in the index, like I mentioned before -- it's easy to find.)

Comment: From what I read they are the same, the site just gives a bit easier instructions (for me at least) and I changed from x86 to amd64 as the computer is a AMD64 bit computer =>

Comment: @UBhapE2: You don't really need to change x86 to amd64 (unless you really want to) -- x86 works on both. x86 might be better since you can then use it on 32-bit-only computers, too.

Comment: I tried to run the AIK tonight on the broken computer. When I boot up from the USB it says "Mising Operating System" What is going on? I followed every instruction that I knew of for the AIK and as far as I can tell it is on the USB fine Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @UBhapE2: I think you haven't correctly set up the USB to be bootable, or you're missing some files. Could you try doing this: (1) Make sure no application is using the flash drive. (2) Assuming your flash drive is `X:` (change this appropriately), open up the command prompt and run `"%ProgramFiles%\Windows AIK\Tools\PETools\x86\bootsect.exe" /nt60 X:` in the command prompt, and try booting again. (I'm not sure if the AIK is stored in `%ProgramFiles%\Windows AIK` or not, adjust that accordingly.) What happens when you try this? (If it doesn't work, let me know; you might be missing `\bootmgr`)

Comment: @UBhapE2: Yay it worked??

Comment: No, but I have not messed with it much. I haven't had time! But the box came today for the laptop to go in for warrenty so off it goes => But I am going to play with AIK some and see what I can get working. It looks interesting and can help issues when I run into situations like I did. We will see what happens. => Thanks for all your help and information.

Comment: @UBhapE2: Ah, I see. No problem, glad it helped! You might also like looking at [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/), btw -- it's a *lot* more tedious to set up, but somewhat more powerful.

Comment: I don't want more tedious this was enough => But who knows I might get bored one day

Comment: @UBhapE2: LOL ok :)

Answer (score 3):

Not per se. You can try running `ntfsfix`, part of NTFS-3G, but there is no proper replacement for `chkdsk` for NTFS drives.

Comment: `ntfsfix` also sets the bit that tells Windows to run `chkdsk` on startup, which may or may not help depending on at what point Windows stops loading.

Comment: How do you run ntfsfix?

Comment: You open a terminal and type it in along with any relevant options. If the command isn't recognized then you'll need to install NTFS-3G, probably from the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I think ntfsfix comes in the standard install now, it's run by doing ntfsfix /dev/devname the devname for windows is usually /dev/sda1 but you can get a list of your partitions and drives by doing ls /dev/sd* if it's a Sata hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

You could try downloading the drive manufacturer's diagnostic utility, which you should be able to run from a boot disk. This would probably cover you for repairing bad sectors if that's the issue. However, if it's just messed up NTFS metadata, you'll probably need a Windows DVD to access repair tools.

Answer (score 0):

You need a preinstalled environment.

I use [Barts PE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/)

Basically you need to run it on another computer running Windows, it will copy your installation files to a CD and make a bootable 'OS' on the disk which gives you a command prompt etc. This will let you run CHKDSK.

Comment: Please delete this answer: The linked website says: `BartPE is no longer available!



We have to move on! Thanks everyone for all your support throughout the years!!!`