# Can you run chkdsk using a Windows boot CD on a Linux NTFS partition?

Tags: windows, linux, chkdsk, boot-cd

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/319923/chkdsk-in-linux) made me wonder: "Can you run chkdsk using a Windows boot CD on a Linux NTFS partition?" Would it cause more problems, or fix them as in Windows?

I can't see why not, but I could not find a definitive answer.

Comment: Did you ever learn more about Linux yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really is no such thing as a "Linux NTFS partition"; Linux does have some support for reading and writing NTFS filesystems, but in the end the Windows tools are considered definitive even for NTFS partitions being accessed under Linux.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense to this non-Linux guy. Maybe one of these days I will learn more about it.

Comment: "One of these days" can be in about an hour if you have a decent internet connection. Just download a Linux live-cd, and VirtualBox or VMWare player, and you're on your way. I personally prefer VBox and always have it available, whether on Linux or Windows. IMO, for somebody that likes to "play with computers", they are great tools. For tech support, testing, development, etc., they're even better.